# Recyclerview not housing all my content but restrict itself to screen height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having issues trying to make my recyclerview house my whole text when i populate them inside but it seems to focus on the screen height of the phone in use and therefore some of my text are lost. How can i make it house them all.

[show partly of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1U7v.png)

layout recycler holder view code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            tools:text="D"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</linear.......................
```

RecyclerBox layout is like these

```
 <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recycleNView">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove `RecyclerView` from `LinearLayout`.

Comment: change the    RecyclerView height to   "match_parent"

Comment: thanks @Rachana, worked perfectly.

Comment: please upvote my comment if it helped you @Cistem ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The root `LinearLayout` in the view holder has

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This will make each row match the `RecyclerView`'s height regardless of its content.

Change it to `wrap_content` and it should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now I understand better. Am grateful @Benito Bertoli